# Javascript regular expression to validate the pattern like 192.169.0.0/24

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, regex

I tried to validate the ip address but to validate /24 , i did not find the solution. Is there any regular expression for to validate pattern like 192.169.0.0/24.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))$
```

[Source:- IPv4 CIDR range](http://blog.markhatton.co.uk/2011/03/15/regular-expressions-for-ip-addresses-cidr-ranges-and-hostnames/)

Comment: Just remember that if you are creating this using the javascript regex literal syntax (e.g. `/my.*regex/gim`), you will need to escape the `/` in this expression using `\/`.

Comment: I tried the above pattern, but it is showing error " / Unescaped delimiter" .

Comment: @Lakshmi:- Hope you have tried the latest version of the code. I have made an edit after my initial answer. As GregL commented you need to escape the / with a \.

Comment: I tried ^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\/([0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-2]))$ this one ,it is working fine.

Comment: @Lakshmi:- Indeed. You just escaped the /

Comment: Thanks. I tried with your latest comment, then it is working.

Comment: This is called CIDR notation, You can find some god example of regex for CIDR notations here http://blog.markhatton.co.uk/2011/03/15/regular-expressions-for-ip-addresses-cidr-ranges-and-hostnames

Comment: @NaveenRamawat:- Thats the same link which I have posted in my answer :)